# Custom String Helper in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I created a helper method that takes a string and replaces all of the newlines with HTML line breaks. I currently have the method in a helper class that needs to be called statically.

How can I simply add my helper method to the builtin C# string class?

So this is what I would like to be able to do:

```
m.MailingAddress = m.MailingAddress.ReplaceNewlines("<br />");
```

This is what I am doing currently:

```
m.MailingAddress = Utility.ObjectExtensions.ReplaceNewlines(m.MailingAddress,"<br />");
```

Comment: Why not just use css for the element (`white-space: pre-line;`) instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You create a static class with extension methods, like so:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string ReplaceNewlines(this string text, string toReplace)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The `this` keyword identifies the method as an extension, in this case to the string class.

Comment: Extension methods bases on Extension Object pattern. It must be noted that extension methods can be used only with . operator ie.  yourValue.YourExtensionMethod(parameter(optional)), and for this you have to include namespace if your extension methods are in different assembly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use extension method:
Extension method should be declared in static class.

```
   public static class Helper
    {
       public static ReplaceNewLines(this string currentStr, string replaceWith)
       {
          return Utility.ObjectExtensions.ReplaceNewlines(currentStr, replaceWith);
       }
    }
```

Click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb383977.aspx) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Create extension method like this (putting your helper to method body for convenience):

```
public static class StringHelpers
{
   public static ReplaceNewLinesExt(this string str, string replacement)
   {
      return Utility.ObjectExtensions.ReplaceNewlines(str, replacement);
   }
}
```

Then after adding namespace in which your helper resides you can use extension method like that:

```
...
var modified = someString.ReplaceNewLinesExt("<br />");
...
```

You can read more about extension methods in [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)